# Translation for the adjective "haunting" (as in "a haunting melody")

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, música, vocabulario

What is the best Spanish translation for the English adjective "haunting" (as in "a haunting melody")? [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=haunting) gives three options: *evocador*, *inquietante* and *inolvidable*. Do any of these really convey what the English word does (something enthralling, beautiful, somber/sad)? What are the differences between these three words?

Comment: "Evocador" pretty much covers it, to be honest I have never heard someone refer to a melody like that (I'm from Mexico), we usually talk about what the melody evokes rather than of its evocative qualities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would help a broader context of the sentence, but I guess "cautivadora" covers most of what "haunting" originally conveys, and it's common to hear the phrase "una melodía cautivadora" - "a haunting melody".

Answer (score 4):

The most appropriate adjective is *"estremecedora"*, because it meets all the characteristics of the adjective "haunting".

Meaning of "estremecedora": to remove (something like a tremor) something inside someone deeply. In this context *"melodía estremecedora"* gives way to be something beautiful, something enthralling and somber / sad.

To explain the differences in the three adjectives you mentioned:

- *Evocador*: That evokes a thing of the past or remembering to another by their relation or resemblance.
- *Inquietante*: lack of tranquility, discomfort (to be uncomfortable with something or someone).
- *inolvidable*: something that is impossible to forget. (I think the latter has nothing to do with what you want, really)

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

A possible of translation is `obsesionante`, whose nearest English equivalent would be `obsessive`

Comment: In what sense would a melody be obsessive?

Comment: @jrdioko: If a melody "bothers" you day and night, it could be "obsessive," or at least "obsesionante."